# zlib inflate in memory

Tags: c, zlib

I have a small buffer with some data (ca. 35'000 bytes).
No i would like to inflate my buffer with zlib.
The buffer is named "pos_in_mem" (void *) and the length of my buffer is len (int *).

I always get a -3 (Z_DATA_ERROR) on that part of code:

```
int ret;
z_stream strm;
unsigned char in[CHUNK];
unsigned char out[CHUNK];

/* allocate deflate state */
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
strm.avail_in = 0;
strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
ret = inflateInit(&strm);
if (ret != Z_OK) {
    printf("zlib init failed");
}
strm.avail_in = *len; // this is my buffer length
strm.next_in = pos_in_mem; // this is my buffer

strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
strm.next_out = out;

//ret = deflate(&strm, flush);
ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH); // here i always get a -3 Z_DATA_ERROR
printf("%d", strm.avail_out);
(void)inflateEnd(&strm);
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mistook `inflate` with `deflate`.

`inflate` - inflation, rise of volume, decompress

`deflate` - deflation, decrease of volume, compress

Good `deflate`/`inflate` examples on [zlib web page](http://cvs.silcnet.org/source/lib/zlib/example.c).

Answer (score 1):

Probably your data is not in the expected format (raw?)

You may try `inflateInit2(&strm, X)`:

- `X = -15` to do a raw inflate.
- `X = 15 + 32` to do a gzip/zlib auto format decoding.
- `X = 15` would do just the same as before.

Other than that it is difficult to say without seeing the deflate code.

Comment: This solved a problem I was having using the zlib library.  Thanks!